# Can people give me tips on jobs to apply to with a Business degree and no experience?

Tags: job-search, careers, entry-level

I was wondering if people could give me some help. I have a degree in Business Administration and have been working an admin job for about a year now. My job does not offer benefits and I can go nowhere in the company.

I have been applying to other jobs for months and never hear back from anybody. This is the only job recently. My last job before this was literally over 10 years ago. I was married for a while and was not working during that time.

Another issue is the only reference I have is my current employer, and most job postings ask for 3.

Can anyone give me any tips on jobs that pay decent that don't require much experience? I would like to ideally make $40,000 a year. I feel that is reasonable with a Business Degree. I currently make $23,000 which I feel I could make without a degree, but all the jobs I look at want so much experience.

Comment: Your employer + 2 coworkers would be your references. They may accept a personal reference, which would mean someone through a hobby or other organization you're in.

Comment: Also it's ambiguous whether current employer is a good reference since you often want to look discreetly.

Comment: You probably won't get a good answer here. We know nothing about you or how to conduct a job search in your locale. This site works much better for specific situations people here have expertise in. For instance I answered your "reference" problem in the above comments because that was a specific question I know something about. But "how to find a new job" isn't answerable except by psychics.

Comment: When you chose this degree, you _should_ have had some idea of where you wanted it to take you.. ?

Comment: @keshlam so how do you explain (say) history degrees? :-)

Comment: @philipkendall: Either aimed at academia, or base for a more marketable degree, or planning to make a living doing something else (related or not), or simply not knowing yet what to do as a profession and marking time... I grant that not everyone goes in focused, but part of getting a degree should include learning what one can do with those skills...?

Answer (score 4):

This is an achievable goal. Take the following steps:

1. **Determine the position you would like to acquire and the industry:** Verify they pay over $40,000 on glassdoor.com. Keep in mind - salaries may vary based on geographic region.

**Tip:** companies that are performing well generally pay better than those that aren't. If the company is publically traded, check the performance of their stock on Yahoo Finance. Look for high growth industries. "Line" jobs - jobs that bring in revenue and are crucial to a companies success generally pay well. Careers that require technical skills also generally command a higher salary.

2. **Approach the job search like a hungry salesperson:** the definition of insanity is doing the same thing and expecting different results. You should ideally want this job as much as a drowning person wants air. You are now selling the product that is you. The first person you need to sell is yourself - believe that you are worth $40,000 a year.

   - Build an impressive resume: use a template (I just found a good one try googling "*The Muse - 41 Best Resume Templates Ever*").
3. Make a killer LinkedIn profile, fill it out completely and add everyone you know. "Your network is your net worth."

   - Reach out to anyone that could possibly help you get an interview. **Do not** ask for an interview or referral, ask to have coffee and learn more about their career or for advice.

-If you need help thinking of impactful statements, use job postings as a guide. For example, I found these on a CareerBuilder listing:

-Addresses and resolves customer financial inquiries via phone, mail, and e-mail.
-Reviews payroll deduction payments for correctness.

3. -**Every time you apply for a job contact an actual person at the company:** This dramatically increases the number of responses you will get. Find people via LinkedIn, Google, and/or the corporate website. It doesn't matter who it is, just contact someone

-Determine if email addresses are valid using http://mailtester.com/, and common business email address formats (quick google search).

4. **Get 2016 skills:** everyone knows Microsoft Office by now, consider taking a course on Lynda, Udemy, Pluralsight, etc. Perhaps learn Salesforce or another CRM software.
5. **Brag about yourself** - it is an uncomfortable thing to do, but in the interview talk yourself up and be confident of your skillset without hesitation. This will land you a high paying salary. Stand tall, smile genuinely and look everyone directly in the eye.

   - Have an elevator pitch - be able to convince someone of your value within 30 seconds - focus on quantitative achievements ("improved efficiency 25% year over year").
6. **Beyond these steps, rinse and repeat.** This is a number game - the more jobs you reach out to, the better your chance will be. If you do not get enough bites, crank up the intensity on one of the steps (Example: get 4 new skills or more in demand skills. Reach out to 20 people, etc.)

**Assorted tips:**

- Do not be deterred by failure, look at it as another step towards your goal. Failure is one of the greatest teachers in life.
- Always ask for the job: why not? Statistically those that ask for the job get it more than those that don't.
- Always follow up to interviews.
- Look your best - hair cut, tan, groom, showered, smell great, etc.
- Research common interview questions and have 5 stories that demonstrate you overcoming adversity and turning a negative into a positive.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not getting any return calls after you submit your credentials, then I would suggest paying a professional to redo your resume.  Once you have done that, set up your linkedin profile to match your new/fresh resume.  Also, if you can, I would try to get recommendations on linkedin.

Writing a good resume, in a modern format, is difficult and not everyone can do it.  Your resume is your first impression right beside linkedin.  It cannot be out-dated, have typos, etc.  Good writing in my opinion is like good art -- and not everyone can be a good artist.

You do have one thing going for you, it is always easier to find a job when you currently have one.  It is much more difficult to find your first job, or a job after you have been laid off for an extended time.

In terms of your job search, network network network.  There are typically "seekers" meetings on the weekends in major citys for those looking for new employment.